# Django admin related objects fields rearrange

Tags: django

in admin.py

```
class PaymentDetailInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PaymentDetail
    extra = 1

class PaymentRequestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PaymentDetailInline]
```

the result is the related fields are at the end, how to put them among other fields?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement [custom templates for the `add_view` and `change_view` views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#custom-template-options). The default templates do not allow mixing inlines among the regular fields.

Comment: How you do that to a specific model?

Comment: `add_form_template` and `change_form_template` are attributes on your `ModelAdmin` instance (`PaymentRequestAdmin` in your case). You need to set them to custom templates. Examine the default change form template (`django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html`)[https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html] and create a new template extending the default one.